# Javascript add class to next element when nested child element is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a menu structure where the Submenu that is hidden is not a child of the menu item. I have a span element inside the main top level link that will serve as an arrow to signify a submenu on mobile. When the user touches the span element I need the dropdown menu to have a class added (Javascript not using jQuery) in order to show it.

Something like this (Note that this is not how I would structure my menu, this is code already on a site that I cannot change)

```
<a href="#">Top Level Menu Item #1
<span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>

<a href="#">Top Level Menu Item #2
<span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>

<a href="#">Top Level Menu Item #3
<span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>
```

So when span is touched or clicked, .dropdown-menu will have a class added to it.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, pick the correct/best answer. If not, please comment what is missing/unclear.

Comment: I just posted this. Is there a time limit here or something? Why so pushy?

Comment: Sorry for appearing pushy. Many new contributors like you ask a question, but forget to ever pick an answer - and noone except the person asking the question can ever do that. So just take it as a reminder.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go with `span.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('visible');`

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('a>span');

for (const span of spans) {
  span.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    span.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('visible');
  })
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown-menu.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Top Level Menu Item #1
  <span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>

<a href="#">Top Level Menu Item #2
  <span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>

<a href="#">Top Level Menu Item #3
  <span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>
```

Please note that I have limited the click listener to the `<span>⇩</span>` , the link itself is not affected.

Let me know if you need IE11-compatible code.

Comment: This answer works but since the span is within the <a> it always visits the link before the dropdown menu is shown. Seems this menu structure won't allow for this.

Comment: @houstonaspen That's what's being taken care of with `e.stopPropagation();` which prevents bubbling of the click event from the inner `span` to the `a` parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can just walk the dom, if that's the structure it will always have HTML wise with something like(providing you add a class to it, a wrapping class/id or something unique to the span):

```
const spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle'))

const addClassToSubmenu = el => {
  el.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('classtoadd')
}

spans.forEach(span => {
  span.addEventListener('click', addClassToSubmenu)
})
```

That'd do.

That's the snippet:

https://codepen.io/Venomzzz/pen/qJyvyN?editors=1010

Comment: So span does not have any classes or IDs. Would I select the 'a span' ?

Comment: Nope, because will select all the a spans in the whole document. You need to identify a way to target just those. Any chance you manage to share that specific structure of code so we can find out how to help you out better?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('a span')` will only select `span` elements which are descendants of `a` elements, not all spans on the page.

Comment: No reason to use external code sites. Instead, create a runnable snippet right within your answer.

Comment: So we are assuming here that the menu is the only part in the document that has a nested span inside a <a>? 

Which is what "document.querySelectorAll('a>span');" does....

Comment: Oh, and cheers for the tip, might do! I find the stackoverflow snippet very clunky to use UX wise, not to mention it bugs and trims out code on a random basis ahah

Comment: I've been using SO snippets for years, with no problems. External code sites are acceptable if SO snippet functionality isn't sufficient (which it rarely is). Given the HTML OP gave, and the fact that they cannot change the HTML (as they stated explicitly), that is the most specific selector that does the job.

Comment: @connexo yes, that's if the OP was working on a 14 html lines of project where nothing else exists, but  as he said "Note that this is not how I would structure my menu, this is code already on a site" he's clearly not. 

Not to mention such wide selectors are never a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try accomplishing this with jQuery next():

Note: you need to add a "menu" class to your  tags and you'd need to expand the mouseout and hover calls to keep your sub-menus from going away when you mouse out of the main menu.

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {display: none }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="menu">Top Level Menu Item #1
<span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>
&nbsp;
<a href="#" class="menu">Top Level Menu Item #2
<span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>
&nbsp;
<a href="#" class="menu">Top Level Menu Item #3
<span>⇩</span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Menu Here</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.menu').hover(function() {
  $(this).next().css("display", "block");
});

$('.menu').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).next().css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: In the question it states that I cannot use JQuery - Thanks anyway!

Comment: `$.hover` requires **two** functions to be passed to it. One for `mouseenter`, one for `mouseleave`.